# Maven build is very slow to load Flex air-config.xml

Tags: maven, apache-flex

I'm stumped as to why a maven build for a project I just started working on is taking so long. The huge slow down is for Flex sdk to load the air-config.xml file. I am using Jenkins, but the build the build is just as slow if I build manually using the same commands. On the command line, it looks like Flex is actually building the .swf, because I see a bunch of warnings etc output that are not outputted in Jenkins.

Here's the build output (Jenkins output so you can see the timestamps). It takes 28 mins to load the air-config.xml file...

> 11:07:12 compile:
>
> 11:07:12 Loading configuration file
> /usr/local/Adobe_Flex_Builder_Linux/sdks/3.3/frameworks/air-config.xml
>
> 11:35:50
> /opt/dpf/.hudson/jobs/myprojectlocation/workspace/branch/web/target/app.swf
> (4694359 bytes)

Any ideas? I'm not finding any info as to why it would take this long to load the file.

Comment: I'm not a `maven` maven, but I think your issue is that your app.swf takes a long time to build, not that air-config.xml takes a long time to load.

Comment: Well, what's weird is if I build just app.swf it builds in 2 minutes. Something in the maven pom.xml file in the root of the project seems to be slowing down the build big time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up the problem was something to do with MAVEN_OPTS settings too high. Lowering the perm gen setting made a massive difference.